# Rate me Illegal state exception

Tags: android

Working on Rate me function ..
getting problem in this ...
i have wrote Rate me function code in a Fragment That is named as RateUss...
   But the problem is that i dont have an exact place where to startup that part of code so then user click in navigation view on button Rate so this rate me dialog will come up

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class RateUss extends Fragment {
private final static String APP_TITLE = "App Rater";
private final static String APP_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.example.rajafarid.navigation";

private final static int DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT = 0;
private final static int LAUNCH_UNTIL_PROMPT = 3;

public RateUss() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //app_launched();

    return container;}
```

rate us function that is define the rate dialog

```
public static void app_launched(Context context){
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("rate_app",0);
    if (prefs.getBoolean("dontshowagain", false)){
        return;
    }
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    long launch_count = prefs.getLong("launch_count", 0) + 1;
    editor.putLong("launch_count", launch_count);

    Long date_firstLaunch = prefs.getLong("date_first_launch", 0);
    if (date_firstLaunch ==0){
        date_firstLaunch = System.currentTimeMillis();
        editor.putLong("date_first_launch", date_firstLaunch);

    }

    if (launch_count >= LAUNCH_UNTIL_PROMPT) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= date_firstLaunch + (DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT * 24 *60*60*1000)){
            showRateDialog(context, editor);
        }
    }
    editor.commit();
}
public static void showRateDialog(final Context context, final SharedPreferences.Editor editor){

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    String message = "If you enjoy Using"
            + APP_TITLE
            + ", Please take a moment to rate the app. "
            + "Thank you for your support!";

    builder.setMessage(message)
            .setTitle("Rate " + APP_TITLE)
            .setIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Rate Now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    editor.putBoolean("dontshowagain", true);
                    editor.commit();

                    try {
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + APP_PACKAGE_NAME)));
                    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "You Have pressed Rate Now Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setNeutralButton("Later", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()         {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "You have Pressed Later Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No, Thanks", new       DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (editor!=null){
                        editor.putBoolean("dontshowagain", true);
                        editor.commit();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(context, "You have pressed No, Thanks button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

}

}
```

stacktrace here ....

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4187)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4040)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3985)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3961)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning the `container` in `onCreateView` which is wrong. You have to create the fragment view and return that, maybe inflating some xml, or return null if fragment doesn't have ui. I reccomend to read this:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating

Comment: Fragment does't have any UI so if i return Null so the Rate fragment is opened but did't show Rate Me dialog...once i initiate this app_launched function in Main activity when i run app its pop up for one time after that its does't work...as its dont have an Rate UI so i can't call View function..

Comment: @farid-raja The popup didn't show until you open the app three times, you are managing with the var `LAUNCH_UNTIL_PROMPT` ,do you have that in mind?

Comment: i initilize this app_launched function in Main Activity like this...RateUss.app_launched(this);...but nothing happen i have start application more then three times...n i am returning null in RateUss class as it dont have any UI..But nothing  happend

Comment: Check if `if (prefs.getBoolean("dontshowagain", false)` is returning true because the popup showed once

Comment: tried with if (prefs.getBoolean("dontshowagain", false) and (prefs.getBoolean("dontshowagain", true)..but same nothing happend..